# Read double numbers from a text file

Tags: arrays, list, text, double, readline

I have a text file and it this file I have something like this:

```
0.003 0.4 6
0.004 0.002 54
0.007 0.001 6
```

I need to read these numbers from text file and save them in a array or list like follow:

```
0.003 0.4 6
0.004 0.002 54
0.007 0.001 6
```

For Example if the Array name is myArray and I need to have some thing like this

```
myArray[0,0,0]=0.003
```

I found some methods which can read double from a text file but in all of them, the array will be like this

```
myArray=[0.003;0.4;6;0.004,0.002;54;....]
```

what should I do? Please help me, I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: So do you need a 1, 2, or 3 dimensional array?  When you say you need to make a call like 'myArray[0,0,0]' that would be a 3 dimensional array.  It looks like whatever your method that you found returns is in a 3 dimensional format too, but since the array is 'flat' the 'z' value is always 0

Comment: Oh nvm you edited the question after I commented.  it looks like you just need to use a 2 dimensional array.  That will set up your array in rows and columns.  If that sounds like what you want to do I'll post a more detailed answer

Comment: Yes, I want to have a 2D array. I will be really appreciative if you post a more detailed answer . Thanks

Comment: @FatemeShirmohammadi - What language?

Comment: I'd suggest you start by picking a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

your program will read one number in each loop round .. so make two counters one for rows and the other one for columns, and increment columns counter each time u read one number, till u exceed number 3 .. then reset it to 0 and increment the row counter .. check out this code:

```
double array[3][3];
int i = 0, j = 0;
double num;
num = inFile.readline();
while ( !inFile.eof() )
{
    array[i][j] = num;
    if ( j == 2 ) // check if its last element in row i
    {
        i++; // move to row i+1 in array
        j = 0; // reset index to first element in row
    }
    else
        j++; // move to next element in array

    num = inFile.readline();
}
```

Comment: But you didn't do any thing for converting text to double !

Comment: as you see .. i already declared the variables with its type .. so no need to convert them